# Why is urllib.request.urlopen blocking in this case?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, urllib

In the following code

```
def sendPostRequest():
  request = urllib.request.Request(myURL, myBody, myHeaders)
  print("created POST request", request)
  response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
  print("finished POST", response)

for i in range(5):
  t = threading.Thread(target=sendPostRequest)
  t.daemon = True  # thread dies when main thread (only non-daemon thread) exits.
  t.start()
```

, the line `print("finished POST", response)` is never reached, while I can observe in the server logs that the request arrived successfully. The line `print("created POST request", request)` is reached however. 
Why is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code makes thread daemon threads.

According to [`threading` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html):

> A thread can be flagged as a “daemon thread”. The significance of this
>   flag is that the **entire Python program exits when only daemon threads
>   are left**. The initial value is inherited from the creating thread. The
>   flag can be set through the daemon property or the daemon constructor
>   argument.

The program maybe end before the response is returned from the server.

Instead of using daemon thread, use non-daemon thread, or explicitly wait the threads to finish started using [`Thread.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join).

```
threads = []

for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=sendPostRequest)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Comment: I believe this is absolutely the main reason, additionally he will also likely see a `TypeError` with trying to print the HTTPResponse, since it won't implicitly be converted to a string. @ptikobj, you will either need to wrap the response in `str()` or do `response.read().decode()` as well as ^.

Comment: @nerdwaller, It will not raises error, but something like `<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x00000000031C2518>`. `print` try to call `__str__` of the objects (or `__repr__`)

Comment: @nerdwaller, Of course, if OP want to print the content, OP should use the way you suggest.

Comment: Ah, that's what I get for trying to concat those, instead of using the print function correctly. Thanks!